# Simple way to figure out how much time a user has been logged into linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm can't come up with a way to display how long a user has been logged on in HH:MM format in 24 hour format.

Comment: 24 hour format is used for date-times (like 10:20PM versus 22:20), not durations. Do you want a duration or do you want the date-time when the user logged in?

Comment: I want to be able to output a line that says for example " John Doe is logged on and as been for 1 hour(s) and 17 minute(s)".

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for the question. You can get statistics about login time of users via the `psacct` package. On most linux systems you need to install this with your favourite package manager. Examples are `apt install psacct` or `yum install psacct`.

Here are some examples:

- `ac -p` will print the total login time of all users in hours. (feel free to convert this into HH:MM format via some bash magic).
- `ac <username>` will print the total time in hours of one particular user.

You can find more information about `psacct` here:
https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/

Comment: I'm not looking for all time. Im looking for time total time since they've logged in.

Comment: you can get a total time since they've logged in via the `last` command.

Comment: When I used last for time logged in it just says "still logged in"

Comment: In this case you need to use the `who` or `w` command. I guess there is not `one command` for your solution. You would need to write a short script that uses `last` when the user is not logged in, if they are logged in then you need to use `who`.